# How to soft code non-english subtitles for movies to be playable on Sony smart TVs

Tags: video, language, unicode, subtitles

I'm looking for a way to soft code non-English subtitles (common formats .srt etc) into movies and they be playable in a Smart TV like Sony Bravia. i tried to use *mkvmerge GUI (mmg)* and it did it very well on English subtitles but non-English subtitles appear as question marks or filled squares on the TV. is there any way or program to get the same results with non-English subtitles too?

i need to mention that i had some DVD movies that i used to play on DVD player and they had subtitles in different languages like turkish, persian, arabic etc. and it was showing it correctly on the TV.

Comment: could you upload one of the subtitle files that are shown incorrectly? (shown like question marks) I want the exact file you are encountering the problem with it.

Comment: i can't find an option to upload files in here but the subtitle file is .srt like any others. it works fine in computer and media players but in TV it's all squares. looks like the TV does not support the subtitle language.

Comment: send them to Google drive or sky drive or ... and give me the link.

Comment: okay here is the link, hope it helps. http://1drv.ms/1x4eWyK

Comment: Now everything seems to be in order. Give it a try. http://1drv.ms/1y7pnDh

Comment: thanks for the try but didn't make any difference. I'm still thinking the lack of support for non-English subtitle languages in TV is the case.